# python module initialization error: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python

Apologies for so much code, but I have sat struggling with this for a few hours now.
I have the below code, but when I run it in AWS Lambda I am getting the error `module initialization error: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

However it is not pointing me to which line in the code is throwing the error, and I'm wondering if I am missing the obvious as I can't see it?

```
for uuid_index, uuid in enumerate(uuid_list):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = '3deo-sensor-data'
    key = 'simulated/config/IoT-sim-config.json'
    obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(json_data, columns= ['organisation'])
    org = dframe.values.tolist()
    TOPIC = org + '/' + 'bitgear/IO-Air'
```

Comment: Run the code line by line in the console to see which line the error comes from

Comment: `TOPIC = org + '/' + 'bitgear/IO-Air'`   org is a list and you are treating it like a string

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you try to concatenate a string to a list. Like you do here:

```
org = dframe.values.tolist()
TOPIC = org + '/' + 'bitgear/IO-Air'
object_str = org + '/' + uuid + '/'
```

You probably want to find something in the list of values and get the string value.  `str(org)` probably won't really work, because I'm guessing you want `org[0]`, but it is hard to tell how you are using it.

EDIT: some advice on getting org as you want it.

if you insist on using pandas

```
data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_data = json.loads(data)
dframe = pd.DataFrame(json_data, columns= ['organisation'])
org = dframe.get('organisation')
```

but that appears to be unnecessary. You already have json_data and can use that:

```
data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_data = json.loads(data)
org = json_data['organisation']
```

Comment: there is a JSON config file  where each JSON is like below ``` {
        "uuid": "2be124d5-c069-493d-a44f-df4f363ce012",
        "organisation": "port_36",
        "device_vendor": "bitgear",
        "device_type": "IO-Air",
        "client_id": "AQ_4"
    }
]``` I initially extract the uuid to simulate data for each and then depending on the organisation contained in the JSON, I want to publish it to the appropriate topic

Comment: why don't you just get the "organization" from the json_data? Why use pandas for that at all?

Comment: using ```org = json_data['organisation']``` I get the error ```list indices must be integers or slices, not str```

Comment: @ioquitteoo what is your json then, really? Your comment shows an object, but is it actually an array?

Comment: if you have a list of items, then you may have multiple `org` values...that's more a functionality question in terms of how you handle that. You may need to something for each one

Comment: yes there are multiple objects in the JSON